CS50 Vanity Plates
I am struggling with the CS50 vanity plates problem and am not obtaining the results I was expecting. Here is a link to the problem and the requirements: https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/2/plates/.
Here is the code that I have tried. I decided to try to write a function for each requirement listed in the problem set and to call these functions inside the is_valid function.
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

def first2(s):
    if s[0:1].isalpha():
        return s
    else:
        return False

def length_ok(s):
    if 2<= len (s) <=6:
        return s
    else:
        return False

def punct(s):
    if s in [".", " ", ","]:
        return False


def is_valid(s):
    first2(s)
    length_ok(s)
    punct(s)

main()


My issue is that my code is not working as expected. When I enter "CS50" as input it prints "Invalid". IS my syntax all wrong? Is it possible to call functions the way I have here? There is another requirement that I have ignored but I will get to that later.

There are a variety of other relevant duplicates as well.  Basically, is_valid always returns None, you forgot to return anything from that function.
